# Could not load file or assembly C++ DLL from a .Net add-in

Tags: c#, c++, dll, deployment, add-in

I have a .Net add-in and within this I have referenced a DLL I have made in C++/CLI. The DLL was designed against the OpenCV API - so now my .Net application can take advantage of the cool graphics capabilities offered by OpenCV.

The problem occurs when I deploy my add-in to other computers. When the user enacts a part of the program that specifically calls upon my C++ DLL it complains about missing the reference:

[image]

I suspect the code does not actually know where the DLLs are located but within my dev environment everything (obviously) works as I will have my environment set up different to your standard build PC.

What am I missing here ?
How can I successfully call DLLs created in C++ from a C# add-in? Bearing in mind add-ins are supposed to simplify the customisation of software like Office etc. This is very important - I have to be able to roll in non-.Net DLLs into my project and my code be able to find them.

My dll is just a plain dll, not a COM compatible dll (maybe it should be?) or should I be decorating my C++ code with __declspec(dllexport) a la https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/exporting-from-a-dll-using-declspec-dllexport?view=vs-2017

Comment: Why the vote down please - maybe I can make this question better if you explain your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

So 2 things

- Use [Dependancy Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to identify any dependancies on your dll and the dlls it uses further down the 'tree' hieracrchy. I found 2 that were missing and it wasn't obvious without this useful tool. Don't be overwhelmed with the results it gives you, just take notice of the missing dlls it's complaining about.
- Make sure your dll is referenced within your project and not outside of it in some other folder where you built it.

This fixed my problem - in general just make sure your dlls are on the same path as your executable.